# PL/SQL 7 day log

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to create log for a single package that will keep data for 7 days. 
So on each run i will write down some log info in table, but i need data only to be there 7 days, after that it can be deleted

My first idea was as simple as it gets, log table and procedure (that is called let's say once a day via job) that deletes everything older than 7 days.

Just wandering, is there maybe a better way, some Oracle built in feature or something else that can come in handy in this case

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the volume? (estimated rows, and average row size)?

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning could help, but it's an expensive option.

I would use the scheduled procedure method -- keep it simple unless you have established a need for something more complex,

Comment: Agreed.  That's what Oracle do themselves with APEX activity logs - except that there are 2 logs and they swap which one is being used periodically, so presumably can truncate rather than delete the data.

Comment: Maybe with synonyms swapping also? You can hack together a similar thing with 7 or 14 tables and a view over the top also -- a partitioned view.